# do DB engines in a docker containers use the host db engines?

Tags: linux, mongodb, docker

If I run mongodb inside a container, does it communicate and uses the host mongodb?
or the container runs its own mongodb instance apart from the host one?

Comment: What if the host doesn't have mongodb installed? For more info, see jubnzv's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. The containerized database engine does not use the host one.

---

The memory of the modern operating system consist of [user space](http://www.linfo.org/user_space.html) and [kernel space](http://www.linfo.org/kernel_space.html). The kernel space is the location where the code of the OS kernel is stored, and executes under. User space refers to all of the code in an operating system that lives outside of the kernel. This includes all kinds of utilities, programming languages, graphical tools and, among other things, database engines. The user space communicates with kernel space using [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call).

The docker environment is built on the two features of the Linux kernel: [namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces) and [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups). Namespace creates a virtually isolated user space and gives an application its dedicated system resources such as file system, network stack, etc. The dedicated namespace allows each application to run independently without inferring with other applications on same host. Cgroups enforces hardware resources limitation, accounting and controlling of an application. With putting namespaces and cgroups together, we can securely run multiple applications with isolated environments on the same host.

That is, if you run your application, say, database engine inside a container, you will get the following picture ([source](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/architecting-containers-part-1-why-understanding-user-space-vs-kernel-space-matters)):

[image]

This means that the containerized application only has access to the resources provided by the namespace and cgroup. Thus, it does not have access to the applications in the user space of the host system.